# fs.renameSync doesn't work with folder that contains another folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

Simply try to rename a folder using:

```
fs.renameSync(currPath, newPath, (err) => {
   if(err) {
      throw err;
   }
   console.log("Directory renamed successfully.");
});
```

I get this error:

> Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename
> 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server/views/app/files/sources/voices/intermediate/11-2'
> -> 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server/views/app/files/sources/voices/intermediate/new-directory-2'
> at Object.renameSync (node:fs:978:3)
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server\mother\mother.service.js:680:22)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
> at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {   errno: -4048,   syscall: 'rename',   code: 'EPERM',   path:
> 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server/views/app/files/sources/voices/intermediate/11-2',
> dest:
> 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Server/views/app/files/sources/voices/intermediate/new-directory-2'
> }

But if the folder I try to rename is empty the function works without issues!!!

How to fix this and rename a folder that contains folders in Nodejs???

**Update:** I noticed if I try to manually rename things when my server is running I get this error too:

[image]

Comment: Seems to be a permission error. So, it seems, that you are not allowed to rename that specific folder.

Comment: if its sync, why did you pass a callback?

Comment: Which OS are you running this on?  It seems you might need admin permission or `sudo` access to the account.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Please have a look at the update.